# Is There A Way To Pass One Variable Containing Multiple Variables And Strings In It From PHP To Python?

Tags: python, php, html, email, variables

I have a Python script that sends an email to my self, based on user inputs in an HTML page. The PHP script extracts the information from the HTML inputs, and sends them to the Python file, which sends an email containing the user inputs. The only problem is, when I transfer the information from PHP to Python, I am unable to do so, with variables that contain multiple variables, strings, or both. For clarification:

A variable that I can send with no problem:

```
$foo = "Hello World!";
```

A variable that I have trouble transmitting:

```
$foo = "Hello World!".$myVar;  // $myVar is defined elsewhere
```

I "export" the variable from the PHP like this:

```
$result = shell_exec("<myPathToPython>/python3 Foo.py $foo"); // $foo is the variable that I want to transmit
```

And I received the variable in Python like this:

```
message = sys.argv[1]
```

In addition, I do have `import sys` and `import os` at the top of my Python.

I am not sure why this is not working, but I would accept any help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show us how the PHP script calls the python script.

Comment: Serialize the data, eg: [`json_encode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)

Comment: @JohnGordon I will edit that in.

Comment: What is your python script getting as `argv[1]`?  Is it the literal value `$foo`?

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you so much. I appreciated your help. Quoting the `'$foo'` helped much, and I am now able to send the information easier, and without the help of JSON. If you could post your answer of quoting the parameter, I could accept it. Thanks!

Also, when I get `argv[1]`, I get a string, which is `"Hello World! Test!"` (because the value of `$myVar` is `Test!`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `$foo` contains spaces (such as `"Hello World"`), then your shell command essentially becomes this:

```
$result = shell_exec("<myPathToPython>/python3 Foo.py Hello World");
```

Then in the Python script, `argv[1]` is just `Hello`, and `World` is in `argv[2]`.

To fix this, put single-quotes around `$foo` in the shell command:

```
$result = shell_exec("<myPathToPython>/python3 Foo.py '$foo'");
```

Then the Python script will receive the entire value in `argv[1]`.